# How to load and group related records in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with an unusual case of loading data in many too many relationship (PostgreSQL). I don't know if I have some wrong assumptions about the data structure or my SQL knowledge is not good enough but somehow I cannot find a solution.

I have a fairly simple data structure:

**Items**

```
item_id | group_id | item_name
```

**Tags**

```
tag_id | tag_name
```

Each item can have many tags, and each tag can be assigned to many items. Items can be grouped by `group_id`.

SQL tables are as expected:

```
items
tags
tags_items - many to many connection table with tag_id | item_id columns.
```

And now, I want to load this data as a set of items, aggregated by group_id, that look more and less like this:

```json
[
  {
     group_id,
     items: [
        {
            item_id,
            item_name,
            tags: [ related_tag_1, related_tag_2 ]
        }
     //...
     ]
   },
   //...
]
```

So I want to group items by group_id so that single record contains array of items assigned to this group, and every item contains array of tags assigned to this item by many-to-many relationship.

I've tried different approaches, but I struggle to achieve it without putting several nested SQL queries. Do you have any suggestions what is the best way, also performance wise, to create such structure? Does not have to be identical, but this aggregation aspect is important.

Best thing I have is this:

```sql
SELECT 
    group_id,
    json_agg(json_build_object(
        'item_id', items.item_id,
        'item_name', items.item_name,
        'tags', array(
            SELECT json_build_object('id', tag_id, 'label', tag_name) FROM tags_items LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_items.tag_id = tags.id  WHERE item_id = items.id
        )
    )) as items 
FROM 
    items
GROUP BY 
    responses.group_id
```

It works, but it's hard to work with this query, to for example add filters by tag etc. Is there a better way to do it

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what you mean by “load this data”. Load it from where to where? I also don’t understand when you say you have a working query but it’s hard to work with - what’s your issue with adding filtering tags, for example?

Comment: I'm looking for a good query that will allow me to load data from tables structured as explained above, and return rows aggregated as on the example

I have a working query but it's ugly. And I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. And this query does not allow me to filter records by tags etc. or I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With no schema or test data I can't run this to verify it runs with no errors, but you might be able to get close to what you're looking for by using a subquery (or using a CTE if that's more readable for you). This lets you filter on the tags after the tags are aggregated for the individual item before the items are aggregated into list of items per group. This could look something like:

```sql
SELECT group_id, json_build_object( 'items', json_agg(item_json) )
FROM (
  SELECT group_id, item_id, json_build_object( 'item_id', items.item_id,
        'item_name', items.item_name,
        'tags', json_agg(
            json_build_object('id', ti.tag_id, 'label', ti.tag_name) 
        ) as item_json
  FROM items i LEFT JOIN tags_items ti on ti.item_id = i.id LEFT JOIN tags t on t.id = ti.tag_id
  GROUP BY group_id, item_id, item_name
  -- filter on aggregate in having clause to remove items that don't have a specific tag in their array of tag names
  HAVING 'healthy' = ANY( array_agg(ti.tag_name) )
 ) item_aggregate
--could also filter in this WHERE clause
WHERE true
group by group_id
```